# SQL Server to PostgreSQL Sum Function

Tags: function, postgresql

I have the following code written **for SQL Sever**.
The objetive of it is to consult any bills with their products, and total amounts per article:

```
Create procedure sp_cons_fact (@id_fact int) as
Begin
     Select * from v_det_fact_art where id_fact=@id_fact
     Select sum(costo_x_art) as Tot_x_fact
     from v_det_fact_art where id_fact=@id_fact
end
```

For PostgreSQL,I have divided that code into 2 blocks.
The first block:

```
SELECT * 
    From v_det_fact_art 
    WHERE id_fact=id_factura ;
```

If I change **id_factura** to 1, it shows:

[image: First Select]

The second block:

```
SELECT sum(costo_x_art) as Tot_x_Fact 
    From v_det_fact_art 
    WHERE id_fact = id_factura ;
```

If I change **id_factura** to 1, it shows:

[image: Second Select]

**v_det_fact_art** is a view that has:

[image: View]

**What I would expect to have is:** 
[image: Final]

As you can see, the column tagged as tot_x_fact is the sum of the content of costo_x_art of each id_fact element (in this case id_fact element 1)

**70003.22 + 300 = 70303.22** in both cases

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is not clear in the error message? You run a `SELECT` query and don't use the results.

Comment: What should your output look like? The sum will return just one value, and the other query will return a set of rows and columns. How do you plan to display these different types of output side by side?

Comment: You have 2 different results sets. What do you want to do with them?

Comment: @Jayadevan I need to show the content of an id_fact in the v_det_fact_art view. In other words show all the registers related to an specific id_fact.  
Plus, I need to use the function SUM to show the sum of that previous id_fact register.

Comment: I wonder @zerkms if there is any way using just one function I can get a view of both result sets

Comment: @Mike Pérez: they are different. What is the purpose of doing it in a single function?

Comment: I had both resultsets in just one stored procedure in SQL Server so I wonder if it is possible to include both in the same function using PostgreSQL @zerkms

Comment: It does not explain why you need that. And you can have 2 result sets in a single SP in postgresql as well.

Comment: I think what you're trying to ask is, is there a way to emulate SQL Server's `WITH ROLLUP` in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You could, I suppose, write a SELECT which will get the sum and show it alongside each record. Use a WITH clause to get the SUM, join it with the other query. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html.

Comment: See if this works in psql. If it does, try putting it in the function.WITH TMP AS (
SELECT sum(costo_x_art) as Tot_x_Fact 
    From v_det_fact_art 
    WHERE id_fact = id_factura
    ) 
    select * from  v_det_fact_art vdfa CROSS JOIN tmp WHERE vdfa.id_fact = id_factura;

Comment: @Jayadevan I edited my post. Do you mean just like this: CREATE function sp_cons_fact (id_factura int) returns TABLE (id_fac integer, id_cliente integer, nombre_cte character varying (40), id_articulo integer, nom_artc character varying (25), cant_artc double precision, precio numeric, costo_ind double precision  ) as $$ 
BEGIN 
WITH TMP AS ( SELECT sum(costo_x_art) as Tot_x_Fact From v_det_fact_art WHERE id_fact = id_factura ) select * from v_det_fact_art vdfa CROSS JOIN tmp WHERE vdfa.id_fact = id_factura; 
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;  ?

Comment: Please see if the SQL works at psql prompt. May be you can make this an SQL function, not plpgsql. Refer http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html. I don't have a lot of experience writing functions, but I think it will work. You will need to add a placeholder for the SUM output also, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example -

```
SELECT * FROM MYT;
 id | val 
----+-----
  1 |  10
  1 |  20
  1 |  30
  2 |  10
  2 |  40
(5 rows)

create function myfunc(x int) returns table (id int, value int, sum_val bigint)
as $$
 WITH TMP AS (
 SELECT sum(val) as Tot_x_Fact 
     From myt 
     WHERE id  = $1
     ) 
     select * from  myt vdfa CROSS JOIN tmp WHERE vdfa.id = $1;
  $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
CREATE FUNCTION
pgp=# SELECT MYFUNC(1);
  myfunc   
-----------
 (1,10,60)
 (1,20,60)
 (1,30,60)
(3 rows)


SELECT MYFUNC(2);
  myfunc   
-----------
 (2,10,50)
 (2,40,50)
(2 rows)
```

Comment: It worked for a few number of returning columns though. With 4 ore more columns it shows: 

ERROR: return type of function declared to return record does not match
SQL state: 42P13
Detail: The final sentence returns too many columns.
Context: SQL function "myfunc"

Comment: In case you are using SELECT * in the function, replace that with actual column names. Ensure that "returns table (" has the necessary number of place holders.

Comment: Thanks! I got just two lines in one column but this is not what I want to get. I will update my post so it becomes clear

Comment: Ok. Please post the output you are getting now and what you are expecting.

Comment: I get with your code:"(1,45,"Jose Hdez.",32,Sala,7,10000.46,70003.22)"
"(1,45,"Jose Hdez.",17,"Computer Hp",6,121.45,728.7)"
I updated my post with my expectation with a table

Comment: I guess there is some issue with the code-rewrite. Could you please paste your code, either here or at http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Aaahh..you missed Tot_x_Fact in the final SELECT. Add it there and add a place holder also.select id_fact,id_clie,nom_clie,id_art,nom_art,cant_art,prec_art,costo_x_art, Tot_x_Fact (add this column.)